# NameError: name 'market_data' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> from pytdx.hq import TdxHq_API
>>>
>>> def get_latest_prices(stock_codes):
...     api = TdxHq_API()
...     with api.connect('119.147.212.81', 7709):
...         market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)
...     api.disconnect()
...
>>> latest_prices = {}
>>> for data in market_data:
...         stock_code = data['code']
...         latest_price = data['price']
...         latest_prices[stock_code] = latest_price
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'market_data' is not defined
>>> return latest_prices
```

market_data is defined in `market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)`, why does it say that it is not defined?

After modifying it to

```
 from pytdx.hq import TdxHq_API

def get_latest_prices(stock_codes):
    api = TdxHq_API()
    with api.connect('119.147.212.81', 7709):
        market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)
    api.disconnect()
    return market_data

latest_prices = {}
for data in market_data:
        stock_code = data['code']
        latest_price = data['price']
        latest_prices[stock_code] = latest_price

return latest_prices
```

I get

```
Cell In[5], line 7
    return market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The reason being is that ```market_data``` is defined within the ```get_latest_prices()``` function and not globally.

Comment: First, you didn't actually CALL `get_latest_prices`, so none of that code ever ran.  Second, `market_data` is a local variable inside that function.  If that's the product of that function, perhaps you should `return market_data` at the end, and do `market_data = get_latest_prices(...)`.

Comment: Your last edit eliminated the source of the syntax error. The idea is that you should add `return market_data` at the end of the function definition, and then `market_data = get_latest_prices(...)` _after (outside) the function definition_.

Answer (score 0):

```
   from pytdx.hq import TdxHq_API


def get_latest_prices(stock_codes):
    api = TdxHq_API()
    with api.connect('119.147.212.81', 7709):
        market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)
    api.disconnect()
    latest_prices = {}
    for data in market_data:
        stock_code = data['code']
        latest_price = data['price']
        latest_prices[stock_code] = latest_price
    return latest_prices
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as Tim Roberts said you didnt' CALL `get_latest_prices` which defines market data. You should CALL it before for-loop.

Second, you cannot substitute and return at the same time in python, at least in version 3.10.

UPDATE:
My apology, I was wrong. You can do it with `market_data := SOME_VALUE`.

Comment: What do you mean by substitute?

Comment: My apology, I was wrong. You can do it with ```market_data := SOME_VALUE```.